# Ligo address being interpreted as string

Tags: ligo

I'm trying to initialise a contract that has an `address option` in its initial storage, but when I provide a valid address, it keeps being interpreted as a `string`; and compilation fails.

I have here a minimal contract showing the `address option` behaviour:

```
(** A host keeps the payment window open *)
type contract_storage = 
[@layout:comb]
{
    host: address option;
}

(* Fails if sender is not host *)
let fail_if_not_host (storage : contract_storage) : unit =
  match storage.host with
  | None -> unit
  | Some host ->
    if Tezos.sender <> host
    then failwith "You are not the host of the contract"
    else unit

let fail_if_unhosted (storage: contract_storage) : unit =
  match storage.host with
  | None -> (failwith "The contract is no longer hosted" : unit)
  | Some _host -> unit

type entrypoint =
[@layout:comb]
    | Remove_host of unit
    | Default of unit


let main (param, storage : entrypoint * contract_storage) : operation list * contract_storage =
    match param with
    | Remove_host _b ->
        let _ = fail_if_not_host storage in
        let new_storage = { storage with host = (None : address option); } in
        ([]: operation list), new_storage
    | Default _d ->
        let _ = fail_if_unhosted storage in
        ([]: operation list), storage
```

Initial storage:

```
{
    host = (Some "tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb": address option);
}
```

This is a valid address: https://tzkt.io/tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb/operations/

When I try to compile it though:

```
echo -e "Initial ligo storage:\n${initial_ligo_storage}"
echo "Compiling…"
ligo compile storage $ligo_file "$initial_ligo_storage" --entry-point main --protocol $tezos_protocol --werror --output-file hostable_seed.tz
```

```
Initial ligo storage:
{
    host = (Some "tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb": address option);
}
Compiling…

Invalid type(s).
Expected: "option (address)", but got: "option (string)".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address itself should be annotated as `address`, like this:

```
{
    host = Some ("tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb" : address);
}
```

See successful deployment:
https://ide.ligolang.org/p/lxt1CWE4AutZLUSL6z1Kow